# How to understand SDecl in idris?

Tags: compilation, functional-programming, idris

I am working on writing a backend for idris , the idris code (abbreviated)

```
main = putStrLn "hello"
```

generated this :

```
(SLet
    (Loc 1)
    (SLet
        (Loc 1)
        (SConst "hello\n")
        (SOp LWriteStr [Loc 0,Loc 1]))
    (SCon Nothing 0 MkUnit [])
    )
```

How to understand the `Loc n` there? is that related to de brujin index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an `SExp`, not a `TT` so it's not yet de Bruijn-ized:

```
Module      : IRTS.Simplified
Description : Simplified expressions, where functions/constructors can only be applied to variables.
```

`SLoc n` is simply a generated identifier, so in your example, the inner `SLet` *does* shadow the outer (unused) `SLet`; it could be sugared into

```
let v1 = let v1 = "hello\n" in writeStr v0 v1
in v1
```

or, alternatively, assigning unique names to variables, to

```
let v1 = let v2 = "hello\n" in writeStr v0 v2
in v1
```

Note that the `Loc 0` argument to `LWriteStr` is not bound in this fragment; I guess that would be the `IO` world token passed to `main`, so the whole of `main` would be

```
\v0 => let v1 = let v2 = "hello\n" in writeStr v0 v2 in v1
```